# Recovering Data from TOSHIBA MK4026GAX (0201)?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an Old TOSHIBA MK4026GAX (0201) that I have not used since 2009 and I have my pictures, videos and etc on it. I have tried to figure out whats wrong using `dmesg` and here is the output:

```
[  298.340791] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[  298.444626] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[  298.444630] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.444631] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  298.444632] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.444633] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  298.444635] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.444636] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  298.444637] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  298.444637] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  298.444642] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[  298.444644] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[  298.548589] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[  298.548592] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.548594] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  298.548595] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.548596] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  298.548597] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  298.548598] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  298.548599] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  298.548600] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  298.652412] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[  298.652415] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given all that errors that the hard disk is giving out, it is pretty clear that it is beyond its end of life. It is not going to work.

You can try to recover data using `ddrescue` or if the  data is very important, you may better pay some money and go with the experts.

Comment: There are a lot of my childhood pics and videos before i come to USA, and I believe that I had windows xp on drive C and I have formatted that drive. Do you think the HDD is physically damaged?

Comment: @Behrad The HDD maybe or may not be damaged. But it surely is past its working age. How old is it btw?